# IEnumerable.Single is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following code which uses Entity Framework:

```
g_getWidgets = from getWidgets in g_libraryEntities.GET_Widgets() select getWidgets;
.
.
.
IQueryable<GET_Fragments_Result> iqueryable = g_getWidgets.AsQueryable<GET_Widgets_Result>();
var nameValueObject = from nv in iqueryable where nv.ID == int.Parse(key) select nv;
widget = nameValueObject.Single();
```

The `widget = nameValueObject.Single();` line throws an exception saying "`The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.`

What is the proper way to perform this function?  I just want to to return an item with the proper ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

> **Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()**
>
> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.
>
> Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

This means that if there are more than one match, only the first one found will be returned.

> **Enumerable.SingleOrDefault()**
>
> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.
>
> Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx

This means that if there is more than one match an exception is thrown. This is useful if having duplicate entries is a data violation.

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish the same thing since you are only looking for a single match where the `ID`s are equal.

```
var nameValueObject = iqueryable.First( o => o.ID == int.Parse(key) );
```

If you don't want an exception to be thrown if a match is not found use `FirstOrDefault` instead.  In that case the return value may be null, but if the item existing is an invariant I would prefer to use `First` and crash early.